# Generate Text File for every new order in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

How can I generate a text file for each new order in Magento.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create a new module (use the [Module Creator](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/1108/modulecreator) extension for a headstart) and bind an Observer to the `sales_convert_quote_to_order` Event.  You can then retrieve the `Order` object from the Event and output the values of interest to a text file using standard PHP file functions (or Zend_File if you wish).

If you search stackoverflow or the web in general, you will find a [number](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) [of](http://www.aschroder.com/2010/01/magento-events-explained-and-a-few-gotchas-avoided/) [tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365930/how-to-trigger-an-event-on-payment-received-in-magento) on how to use the Event-Observer model, you will just need to adapt that to the specifics of the Event you are interested in.

HTH,
JD

Answer (score -1):

You can also override succesAction in OnepageController from Checkout module in Mage. This action is always called after successed new order in Magento.

You can use code:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getLastOrderId())

$ourFileName = "order_".$order->getId().".txt";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($ourFileHandle, 'Some text');
fclose($ourFileHandle);
```

You can put this part of code just before Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear();

Comment: I would recommend that you do **NOT** override such an important controller.  It will cause major issues with upgrading/patching Magento in future.  The Observer method is much less invasive.

Comment: Also, using a `die()` statement in the successAction of checkout? That's a really really bad idea.  If you have a failure that doesn't relate to the customer's actions, then at least put the code in a `try/catch` block and log it to `exception.log`.  Seriously.

Comment: Sorry for die(). I just wanted to show how to create file because it was missing in your post.
And your advice to use try/catch block is correct off course. I'm new and i forgot about obvious things.

Comment: @Lukasz - no problem, it's just that so many people simply Google an answer and copy/paste without ever stopping to realize that it was just demo code and not ready for production.  While it's reasonable to expect that most programmers would avoid the `die()`, there are some rookies who might not.  I have this problem with a lot of textbooks, it really irritates me that their examples are not production quality code.  Sorry for the rant!