# Create "post-checkout" Magento extension overview

Tags: php, magento

How could I create a "post-checkout" Magento extension? All I want it to do is do a specific action post-checkout, say, call a function.

I've had a read through its docs and a few articles (which could be a bit more noob-friendly). Some suggest adding code to `success.phtml`, but I don't want to overwrite any of Magento's "existing" files.

**I don't need an in-depth answer, just a rough overview**—what files to create, where to put them, and how to be able to "install" them on someone else's computer. I can figure the rest for myself (I'm a veteran Python dev, but I'm interested in making a quick Magento extension).

(I've read ["How to create a simple hello world module in Magento?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-module-in-magento) but it's not *exactly* what I need.)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the dispatchEvents and an observer file. In this case, try checkout_onepage_controller_success_action  or checkout_multishipping_controller_success_action.

Comment: That sounds good—event-based. There's a ["tutorial" answer for that on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365930/how-to-trigger-an-event-on-payment-received-in-magento) too. Good stuff